# Order of appearance for if/else in list comprehension based on for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

Learning list comprehensions and discovered that *if/if-else* statement can be placed in different order of apperance in expression.
In example, starting understanding list comprehension construction from *for loop* schema:

```
positive = []
for number in numbers:
    if int(number) >= 0:
        positive.append(int(number))
    else:
        positive.append(0 - int(number))
```

can be evaluated to:

```
positive = [int(number) if int(number) >= 0 else 0 - int(number) for number in numbers]
```

But

```
positive = []
for number in number:
    if int(number) >= 0:
        positive.append(int(number))
```

goes to:

```
positive = [int(number) for number in numbers if int(number) >= 0]
```

I know that one of useful technique for creating list comprehension is to read *for loop* from top to down and put them in one line (a little shortcut of course). 
But why those 2 examples put if / if-else statement once in front and secondly in the end of construction?

Comment: In the first example, the `if` and `else` are not actually part of the list comprehension. They are just a conditional expression used as the value.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're choosing between two options; but in either choice, you're adding to the list. Whatever comes before the `for` is added to the list.

In the second case, you're only adding to the result list in one option. Whatever comes after the `for` construct on the right decides if something is added at all.

---

If you want to pick what's added between (usually two) options, use the first. If you what to pick if something is added at all, use the second.